# smartgwt add blank row in ComboBoxItem or allow user to set blank value

Tags: java, user-interface, smartgwt

I am trying to add blank row with **null** value in ComboBoxItem of `smartgwt` which is already bind to data source coming from database.

I have tried changes in service layer, controller layer and database too, but that was not recommended by my senior.

All I need to do changes on `UI layer` only.

Comment: "Can't share code"?  Really?  Are you completely unable to come up with a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem?  If so, then you really can't expect anyone to come up with an answer for it, can you?

Comment: @TobySpeight don't be so hard on the guy. I don't think code is needed to properly answer this question, as it is a general 'how-to' question, instead of a 'what's wrong with my code' one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Special Values ComboBox](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#specialvalues_combobox_category) SmartGWT showcase demo. I think it does what you want.

Here is an extract **taken from that demo's code** (although I recommend you to look at it and study the code to see what's best in your case):

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();  
hashMap.put("**EmptyValue**", "None");  
hashMap.put("-1", "Not Applicable");  

ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();  
comboBoxItem.setName("filteredCombo");  
comboBoxItem.setTitle("Choose an item (ComboBox)");  
comboBoxItem.setAddUnknownValues(false);  
comboBoxItem.setOptionDataSource(ItemSupplyXmlDS.getInstance());  
comboBoxItem.setDisplayField("itemName");  
comboBoxItem.setValueField("itemID");  
comboBoxItem.setPickListWidth(300);  
comboBoxItem.setPickListFields(skuField, itemNameField);  
comboBoxItem.setSpecialValues(hashMap);  
comboBoxItem.setSeparateSpecialValues(true);
```

Comment: Hey @carlossierra, your solution seems to be work for me. But in my smartgwt these method setSpecialValues(LinkedHashMap<String,String> hashMap);  and setSeparateSpecialValues(true); are not present, may be due to Version 3.0p. am I right ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with v3.0p, but I guess that can be true. Can't you upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: Hi @carlossierra , _This feature is of Version 6.0_ . I discussed with team. No, we can't upgrade to latest version. Stuck again at Starting position. Is there any other way where we can manipulate datasource or by any other means.

Comment: One way that comes to mind is to bind this ComboBoxItem to a DataSource that has a custom fetch operation specified (in the ds.xml DataSource descriptor). The server class that is invoked when the fetch operation is performed can execute the original DSRequest and then add the "Empty" row to the DSResponse data before returning it to the client.